# Retrieved acces database data doesn't show up in listbox

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access, listbox

I'm trying to get some information that is stored into a MS Acces Database into my listbox. When in run the following query I don't get a error or something, but it also doesn't display the data in the listbox.

```
   connection.Open();
            try
            {
                string q = " SELECT Behandelingen.Behandeling FROM PatientBehandeling INNER JOIN Behandelingen ON PatientBehandeling.BehandelingID = Behandelingen.BehandelingID WHERE PersoonID = '" + textBoxUsername.Text + "'";
                command.CommandText = q;

                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(reader["Behandeling"].ToString());
                        listBox1.Refresh();
                    }

                }
                reader.Close();

            }
```

Comment: Are you really sure your query returns data? `PersoonID` column is really character typed? Based on it's name, it sounds as numerical.

Comment: Debug your code and see what is happening.

Comment: I made the PersonID on purpose a string type so I would not get any problems with wrong types. By the looks of debugging, I don't think it gets any data. But don't where the error comes from.